# Issues with AlpineJS & Vanilla DataTables

Tags: javascript, datatables, alpine.js

I got this layout I'm using DataTables to deal with my data (pagination, sorting & search) - https://github.com/fiduswriter/Simple-DataTables

I'm using AlpineJS to manage those tab implementation and on the first page reload, everything works fine & when I switch to another tab, it doesn't work at all. I even tried it with jQuery datatables but same thing went there as well.

Currently, the vanilla JS datatables got various events and options to call but none of them is working in my case.

JS Guys, Can you help?

Answer (score 3):

This answer will work better if you're using Alpine.js v2+ since I'll be using `x-init`. The pre v1.7 equivalent to this would be to do everything mentioned in `x-mounted`.

You should be able to integrate third party libraries that accept a DOM Node (which the `new DataTable()` constructor supports) using `x-init` (to run the initialisation/integration) and `x-ref` (so that Alpine provides you with the DOM Node you want to initialise the plugin to).

The following snippet initialises a `dataTable` instance property using the `DataTable` constructor invoked on the element with `x-ref="dataTable"` (using `$refs.dataTable`).

```html
<div
  x-data="{}"
  x-init="dataTable = new DataTable($refs.dataTable)"
>
  <table x-ref="dataTable"></table>
</div>
```

In principle you should also delete the DataTable instance when the Alpine component/app unmounts. You can do this by using a function for the x-init hook and returning an "unmount"/"destroy" callback from it (note: this is a 2.x feature).

```html
<div
  x-data="{}"
  x-init="() => {
    dataTable = new DataTable($refs.dataTable);
    return () => {
      dataTable.destroy();
    }
  }"
>
  <table x-ref="dataTable"></table>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I am trying to add alpine dropdown component in datatable column after datatable initialization completes but data attached with x-data is not working after datatable is initialized. Can you help with this?